# Netgear DG834Gv4 not giving out DHCP addresses on wireless lan

Tags: wireless-networking

My netgear DG834Gv4 is happily distributing ip addresses on it's wired lan, but it is not distributing them on it's wireless interface.

If I set a static IP address it works fine.

I have looked over the Netgear support forums and upgraded to the latest firmware version, still no good.

Any ideas? Is there a checkbox that I am missing somewhere ?

Comment: you're certain that the clients are configured correctly?

Comment: Has DHCP over wireless ever worked?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a different model of Netgear router, and I could not fix it until I re-flashed the firmware.

After that, everything started working again.

Weird.